# Calibrate Odometry and Gyro,What is the principle calibration?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, turtlebot, gyro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello. i am using tuetlebot with the Gyro ADXRS613,and i got two params named turtlebot_node/gyro_scale_correction
turtlebot_node/odom_angular_scale_correction
but what's the meaning about two params? and What is the principle calibration? is there some relevant literatures i can study? thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64248/calibrate-odometry-and-gyro,what-is-the-principle-calibration?/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I doubt there is relevant literature, this is a very basic calibration. The robot basically aligns to a wall, spins around several times at different speeds, and at the end tries to generate scale corrections for the gyro and odom such that the values would be correct for those rotations (where the ground truth is based off the laser-scanner detection of the wall to which it keeps aligning).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-06-12**:
I assume you have looked into this? http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrate%20Odometry%20and%20Gyro Note that calibration is very important for localization & navigation.